# XPTY0020 The required item type of the context item for the child axis is node(), but the supplied expression {.} has item type xs:anyAtomicType

Tags: html, xml, error-handling, xls

i always receive the error message:
XPTY0020  The required item type of the context item for the child axis is node(), but the
supplied expression {.} has item type xs:anyAtomicType

for my code.
I just want to calculate how many people have the same eye colour. the xml set has two entities (person and eye-colour) and they somehow need to be connected in order to count the number.

```
                                <li class="list-group-item">Total of people with 
                                    <xsl:value-of select="key('Eye_colour-by-id',id)/Colour"/>-coloured eyes:
                                    <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(/Data/Eye_colours/Eye_colour/Colour)">
                                     <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ': ')"/>
                                     <!-- <xsl:value-of select="count(/Data/Persons/Person[@id=/Data/Eye_colours/Eye_colour[Colour=current()]/Ref_id])"/> -->
                                     <xsl:value-of select="count(Person[@id=/Data/Eye_colours/Eye_colour[Colour=current()]/Ref_id])"/>
                                    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Within `xsl:for-each select="distinct-values` the context item is going to be one of the distinct values (always a string), so when you do `count(Person[@id=...])` it doesn't have a context node for selecting `Person` elements. I don't know enough about your XML to correct the problem, but you probably need to bind the context node to a variable outside the for-each

`<xsl:variable name="nnnn" select="."/>`

and then use the variable within the for-each

`count($nnnn/Person[@id=...])`

But if you can use `distinct-values()` then you can also use `xsl:for-each-group`, and that would seem a better way of tackling this requirement.